# How combine menu with listview in Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, drawer, navigationview

I would like to combine two menus. One from xml and the other from generated by the code.
It is possible?
How can I do this?

```
 <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/nav_header_main" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_item"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:textColor="#424242"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

ow can i attach a menu (XML) under the menu that is generated by the code?

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single"  android:id="@+id/main_group">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="@string/menu_home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="@string/menu_gallery" />

    </group>

</menu>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The easiest thing to do would probably be to actually use `NavigationView` as it's meant to be. Currently, you're using it as a container, which is somewhat pointless, and goes against its design. Your header can be set as its `app:headerLayout`, and the menu as its `app:menu`. Then, instead of using a `ListView` for the dynamically generated items, simply add them to the menu in another `<group>` inserted above the one you have now. [Here's a basic example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11M6pW1S7jR63bsO6OBu_n1pQqwIdZ0du/view?usp=drivesdk) that shows how to modify that menu at runtime.

Comment: What do you want to have as your output?

Comment: I've thought about it. ListView is just an example becouse I'd like add the ExpandableListView. Each row will contain two textview. I can turn away from  ExpandableListView but I need a custom row (item of menu).

Comment: Well, in that case, the easier route would probably be to get rid of the menu resource altogether, and just add two footer `View`s to your `ExpandableListView`. If you do that, get rid of the `NavigationView` as well, and make the vertical `LinearLayout` your drawer by setting `android:layout_gravity="start"` on it, and giving it a definite width; e.g., `android:layout_width="240dp"`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I would like to get something like that: https://drive.google.com/open?id=19nRJ66ypCYt-EmRuw0sJumelXWiQgN5G
line yellow: menu static ex: from xml
line green: by code

Comment: If you're going to use `ExpandableListView`, then you'll have full control over it, so you can make it look however you like. I guess I'm not sure which way you want it – above or below – but the the two "constant" items could be added as headers or footers, or even as another `View` type within the `Adapter`.